# VS 2013.1 wont expand variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, variadic-templates, compiler-bug

```
template <class T>
struct identity
{
    virtual ~identity() {}
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct _function_signature : _function_signature<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

template <class R, class... A>
struct _function_signature<R(A...)> : identity<R(A...)>
{};
```

This piece of code compiles just fine in `g++` but refuses to do so in `msvc` with the following error:

```
error C3520: 'A' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context
```

---

```
ms vs ultimate 2013 v 12.0.30110.00 update 1
g++ (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.1
```

---

Complete version of the errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: tests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>d:\projects\tests\tests\main.cpp(30): error C3520: 'A' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context
1>          d:\tests\tests\main.cpp(162) : see reference to class template instantiation 'fl<void (void),>' being compiled
1>d:\projects\tests\tests\main.cpp(38): error C3520: 'A' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context
1>d:\projects\tests\tests\main.cpp(46): error C3520: 'A' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context
1>d:\projects\tests\tests\main.cpp(54): error C3520: 'A' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Compiling version on [stacked croocked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/243f2c28eab6fe66).

Comment: Just a side-note: Don't have names in the global namespace that starts with underscores, those names are reserved by the C++ specification.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Its inside a couple of namespaces and inside another class, but thanks for the note.

Comment: A `.cpp` file containing nothing but the above fails to compile on which line, and that is the only error message, is that right?  Curious: why is `~identity` virtual, and does it matter for error?  If you remove the base `template` implementation, does it matter?  Do you have to instantiate to get the error?

Comment: @Yakk Added the requested info + a compiling version of how it should work.

Comment: Moving `_function_signature` specializations outside the class definition helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in MSVC -- [Clang](http://goo.gl/VdHvU0) and [ICC](http://goo.gl/SY1AXz) both accept this code...